# Use virtual drive from samba source

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, file-sharing

I wounder how could I use virtual disk (*.vdi) file located under samba (LAN) - so many of users can use same virtual machine and all software installations and updates w/o any need to sync between each other. I can do this in Win version of Virtual Box, but didn't manage to do this in Ubuntu.

How to mount VDI from Samba?

PS I use latest version (3.0.8)

here is situation:
I have server, let's name it "A". On this host in shared directory (/vm) image.vdi file is located.

I wanna use this file with VirtualBox from my computer "B" (ubuntu). But there is no option to use external addresses in open dialog for "virtual disks" - I cannot just write //a/vm/image.vdi to pick up this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to mount the share on your VirtualBox host, eg:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=username,password=password //a/vm /mnt/vm-share
```

If you leave off the `password=password` option, this will prompt you for a password.  Other handy options might be `uid=` and `gid=`.  See the [`mount.cifs` manpage](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html) for more options.

Once you have the share mounted, you can give the VirtualBox a local path to the VDI file (eg, if you have mounted the share at `/mnt/vm-share`, the file from your example should be accessible at `/mnt/vm-share/image.vdi`).

**Note:** This is how you would do it for one VirtualBox host.  This method may have problems if it's active on multiple hosts concurrently.

Comment: ok. thank you. I also thinked about concurrency but for now it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to mount your vdi file on your Ubuntu machine ([here's](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=17574) a 
how-to - but I haven't tried it at all) and then share the directory where you have mounted the file using Samba.

Comment: I've updated discription with details - please look at it. Thank you.